# drop_duplicates() doesn't work in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am working on my pandas tutorial. Below is my dataframe

[image]

I am trying to drop duplicated header row using

```
df_FDNY_dataset.drop_duplicates(subset=['FacilityName','FacilityAddress','Borough'])
```

But drop_duplicates() function doesn't work in this case. Could you help me understand the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the duplication??

Comment: Just a comment that you could easily find this by 5-min searching/googling and no need to ask here! And always to keep in mind that it is best practice to provide a working data (even tiny) to allow people to reproduce your problem fast. Here is easy, but there are cases that a snapshot won't help! Happy learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you want to drop the 1st row, which is indexed as 0 in the DataFrame.

This can be done by

```
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The header row is not duplicated, it is a row of the data frame (see index 0 attached with it, The actual columns don't have any index number). That's why you can't remove it using `drop_duplicates`. If you want to remove it after having it in data frame, then

```
df = df.iloc[1:,:]
```

where `df` is your data frame.